# Extern and const in C++

Tags: c++, constants, extern

I've seen several posts about this issue, but none of them explains well my concern, so I'll try to explain here what I understand and please correct me if I'm wrong.

Suppose I have a header file with the following declaration:

```
//definitions.h
extern const float fallingTime;
```

Now, I have two source files that want to use this declaration.

```
//source1.cpp
#include "definitions.h"
const float fallingTime = 0.5f;
//use fallingTime 

//source2.cpp
#include "definitions.h"
//just use fallingTime (no definition required)
```

This is what I do; but now, assume this other way to proceed.

```
//definitions.h
const float fallingTime = 0.5f; //Note that I don't use extern now

//source1.cpp
#include "definitions.h"
//just use fallingTime (no definition required)

//source2.cpp
#include "definitions.h"
//just use fallingTime (no definition required)
```

As I concluded from reading several sources, the advantages of the former approach is that it saves memory and compilation time, because memory allocation only occurs one (in the definition in source1.cpp), whereas in the latter approach memory allocation happens in every source file that includes definitions.h (source1.cpp and source2.cpp). Is that correct?

Finally, what would imply using extern and defining the constant at the same time? Would be equivalent to the former approach?

```
//definitions.h
extern const float fallingTime = 0.5f;
```

Comment: checkout the external and internal linkage for const.

Comment: Its also compiler dependent..

Comment: Not relevant to any answer but why are you using `float`? The only performance gain over a `double` will be to and from the RAM chips, not on the CPU itself (which probably uses 80 bit floating point). Btw 0.5 can be atypically represented exactly in floating point as it's a dyadic rational.

Comment: It is compiler dependent, but the second approach will most likely see `fallingTime` optimized away during constant propagation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `const float fallingTime = 0.5f;` is defined in a header, a translation unit may or may not store the value in the data section of your binary.

If no code in a translation unit takes an address or reference to `fallingTime` there is no reason for the compiler to allocate the value in the data section at all. The compiler is likely to replace usage of `fallingTime` with its value because its definition is available in every translation unit at compile time.

With `extern const` the generated code will have to load the value of `fallingTime` from memory because its definition is not available at compile time in any other translation unit but the one that defines the value of `fallingTime`.

Comment: So, are you saying that under those circumstances both ways are equivalent in memory and compilation time?

Comment: @FrancisMoy Updated the answer for you.

Comment: Ok, my reasoning was mistaken. Then, if the second approach may be more optimal (from the compilation time / memory point of view), why is it usually suggested as best practice the first approach? Which is the advantage of using extern then for constants? The only problem of the second approach would be the one explained by @TomTanner?

Comment: @FrancisMoy _Why is it usually suggested as best practice the first approach?_ - Where? _The only problem of the second approach would be the one explained by TomTanner_ - I do not think his answer is accurate.

Comment: Regarding the best practice, I've just read it in several posts (including here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9649405/c-best-practices-for-constants), but I guess it's not as "best practice" as I thought in the first place. So, just to wrap up: the second approach allows some compiler optimizations for the generated code (constants propagation), but it could entail longer compilation times because each .cpp must be recompiled when the definition of the constant changes. In case of using extern, we would have the opposite implications. Can we agree on that?

Comment: @FrancisMoy Well, `const` at global and namespace-scope level implies internal linkage, i.e. `static const` is the same as `const`, but not `extern const`. This behaviour was specifically implemented in C++ to avoid using macros for constants, http://stackoverflow.com/a/998457/412080... Agree with you.

Answer (score -2):

The problem with the latter one is that under C++ prior to C++11 depending on your compiler, you could get a linktime error as there's no address for fallingTime. The language *requires* that you instantiate it in precisely one translation unit and gcc in particular is quite strict about that.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand. With the "latter one", do you refer to using extern and the definition together?

Comment: @FrancisMoy the code in "assume this other way to proceed"

Comment: So, with extern (external linkage), we're forcing that the constant is assigned a memory address, which can be necessary if taking a reference or the address of the constant, right?

Comment: no. the only thing that forces a memory address is to define it in a source file (more or less. there are subtleties)

Comment: Global and namespace-scope `const` objects have internal linkage (implicit `static` applied) since C++98, the declaration is the definition, no other definitions are necessary. Unless explicitly marked as `extern`. Your answer is incorrect.

Comment: the version of gcc we have insists you provide an instance. It may be aa bug in that version, but it's not one we're likely to change off soon