# C++ How to share constants with extern between cpp - Error: storage class specified

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, constants, extern

I've the header file in which I declare some constants with extern:

```
#ifndef CONSTANTS_H
#define CONSTANTS_H

#include <string>

class Constants
{
    public:
        Constants(){}
        extern const std::string DELIMITER;
        extern const std::string FILENAME;
        extern const int BLUCAR;
        extern const int REDCAR;
        extern const int EMPTY;
        extern const int SPARSE_LIM;
    protected:
    private:
};

#endif // CONSTANTS_H
```

Then in the source I define them like this:

```
#include "constants.h"

extern const std::string DELIMITER = ",";
extern const std::string FILENAME = "cars.csv";
extern const int BLUCAR = 1;
extern const int REDCAR = 2;
extern const int EMPTY = 0;
extern const int SPARSE_LIM = 5;
```

Why the compiler gives me Error: storage class specified for 'DELIMITER'?

Comment: Deleting the class definition, constructor and the access modifiers the error is solved. Is it the right way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, these don't seem to be class members. The way you're using `extern` it looks like you intended for these to be free. Perhaps in a namespace. Take them out of that class.

Then, when you define them, leave out the `extern`.

In this context it means "find this variable elsewhere". You don't want to find it elsewhere. It's *here*!

```
// Header
namespace Constants {
   extern const std::string DELIMITER;
   extern const std::string FILENAME;
   extern const int         BLUCAR;
   extern const int         REDCAR;
   extern const int         EMPTY;
   extern const int         SPARSE_LIM;
}


// Source
namespace Constants {
   const std::string DELIMITER  = ",";
   const std::string FILENAME   = "cars.csv";
   const int         BLUCAR     = 1;
   const int         REDCAR     = 2;
   const int         EMPTY      = 0;
   const int         SPARSE_LIM = 5;
}
```

Remember, you'd do the same for `static` object definitions!

Comment: I understand what you say, but I need to define them in the source file so that I can include the header file in which they are only declared. In that way when I modify a value, the files in which constants.h is included don't need to be recompiled.
I don't know if what I'm saying is right, but I understood that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9649405/c-best-practices-for-constants

Comment: @rh0x: Yes, define them in the source file. I showed you how.

Answer (score 3):

I think you either want to use static members in your class, use a namespace instead of a class, or put your constants in the global namespace.

For static members:

```
class Constants
{
    public:
        Constants(){}
        static const std::string DELIMITER;
        static const std::string FILENAME;
        static const int BLUCAR;
        static const int REDCAR;
        static const int EMPTY;
        static const int SPARSE_LIM;
    protected:
    private:
};
```

and in your source file

```
const std::string Constants::DELIMITER = ",";
const std::string Constants::FILENAME = "cars.csv";
const int Constants::BLUCAR = 1;
const int Constants::REDCAR = 2;
const int Constants::EMPTY = 0;
const int Constants::SPARSE_LIM = 5;
```

However, it looks like your class is more like a namespace than a class, since there would be no point in making instances.

But there is another option.  You may not even want to use a class or a namespace, but just have them all in the global namespace:

```
// header
extern const std::string DELIMITER;
extern const std::string FILENAME;
extern const int BLUCAR;
extern const int REDCAR;
extern const int EMPTY;
extern const int SPARSE_LIM;

// source
const std::string DELIMITER = ",";
const std::string FILENAME = "cars.csv";
const int BLUCAR = 1;
const int REDCAR = 2;
const int EMPTY = 0;
const int SPARSE_LIM = 5;
```

Comment: Yes, you are right! As also 'Lightness Races in Orbit' says probably the best option is to use a namespace. Thank you!

Comment: @rh0x: Note that you only need a namespace if you want to group them in some way, such that you use your namespace prefix for access.  If you just want to be able to use `DELIMITER` instead of `Constants::DELIMITER`, then putting it in the global namespace may be what you want.